# How do I set the ABP display language at the start of an angular application?

Tags: angular, abp

I'm working on a project that has started as an MVC UI project. However, we decided to use Angular for a small part of the app. I was able to make it work with the different ABP services; however, I'm currently stuck on trying to set the language used by the localization services when the angular app starts, so that it's the same as the one configured by the user in the MVC part of the app.

We are using ABP version 3.0.5.

My idea was to get the language chosen by the user on the ASP.NET side, using a web service, and then store this choice in the Angular data store using `SetLanguage`. Using the language selection code from the default Angular template, I came up with something like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'MyAngularApp';

  constructor(
    private userInfo: UserInfoService,
    private store: Store) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userInfo.getLanguage().subscribe(result => {
      this.store.dispatch(new SetLanguage(result));
    });
  }
}
```

In this snippet of code, the `getLanguage` function works and returns a correct language code (like `en` for example). However, it seems the call to `this.store.dispatch(new SetLanguage(result))` messes with the angular router and resets my route to its current value. For exemple, if I want to navigate to `https://localhost:12345/angularApp/?val=00112233` changing the language would cause the app to be redirected to `https://localhost:12345/angularApp/`.

Did I use the correct approach to initialize the app language ? What would you recommend for such a task ?

Comment: What is the version of your ABP packages?

Comment: @MehmetErim I have edited the question to add this information (3.0.5)

Comment: I can not reproduce the problem in v3.1. Can you try it again by downloading a new sample solution?

You can replace the app.component with this content:
https://gist.github.com/mehmet-erim/4ff8b5d70685a103e3e06bf75a3facf5